# Chef: How to set EDITOR for knife

Tags: chef-infra

When I run below command I get the error mentioned below:

```
$ knife node edit hostname.domain.com
ERROR: You must set your EDITOR environment variable or configure your editor via knife.rb
```

I wanted to set editor value in the knife.rb but I am not able to find which option would correspond to the editor. I have gone through below links which explain various options supported by knife.rb:

[http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife.html](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife_optional_settings.html)

http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife_optional_settings.html

I know I did not overlook above links but i can;'t find an option which is relevant to setting editor value.

Could you point me to the correct options whihc will help me set editor for knife.

Thanks.

Comment: It's good practice to have the `EDITOR` environment variable set anyway, as it's used by many processes. You can export it in your `~/.bashrc` file (if using bash). Mine points to `/usr/bin/vim`, but you could use your editor of choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we check out the [source code](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/core/node_editor.rb) (`assert_editor_set!` method), we can see that it checks for `config[:editor]`. Pretty logically `knife[:editor]` in knife.rb should work.

`knife[:editor]` worked for me in latest Chef (v.11.4.4). But in older version (v10.26) it does not work.

Comment: thanks. `knife[:editor]="/usr/bin/vim"` worked. And mine is 11.4.4. So Life is good.

Comment: knife[:editor] is the preferred and easiest method, but you can also set the environment variable EDITOR as well

Answer (score 25):

You can set the EDITOR variable in two ways. First way is to SET EDITOR variable in command line.

```
export "EDITOR=nano"
```

OR

```
export "EDITOR=vim"
```

Second Way is set EDITOR in knife.rb file.

```
knife[:editor]="vim"
```

OR

```
knife[:editor]="nano"
```

nano is also a editor shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: where is knife.rb

Comment: knife.rb is probably in your `~/.chef` directory

Answer (score 5):

for visual editors (like atom or code) you'll need to export EDITOR variable using '-w' switch:
export EDITOR='atom -w'

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, chef doesn't recognize 'vi' as an editor so set vim or nano only.

Comment: is there a github issue about changing this?